# Dedicates categories for ext news

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, tx-news

When I create categories in different directories, all these categories (totally) were listed in the backend of the plugin "news".
In the news items and also in the list-plugin e.g.

How can I tell news to list only the categories of a special dedicated directory (or page)?

Answer (score 2):

The configuration can be changed in the Extension Manager > news: There is the field `categoryRestriction`. Check the full configuration manual described in the manual: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/AdministratorManual/Configuration/ExtensionManager/Index.html#categoryrestriction

For next time, please always include the TYPO3 Version and extension version(s). thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nice, it works, but only during creating a news item.

If you put a plugin (list e.g.) into a page, the complete list of existing categories is listed, not only those from the dedicated News directory?

Comment: true, that is currently a bug/missing feature. I added it at https://forge.typo3.org/issues/77867